# How to add objects to list without having array brackets

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, arraylist

I have a for loop in which I add some attributes to the object and at the end I need to have a string (to pass it as a query parameter)

I need

```json
{"items":[{"itemsCode":"item1","isAvailable":false}],"isActive":false},{"items":[{"entryCode":"item2","isSelected":true}],"isActive":false}
```

When I try

```java
List<List> itemsList= new ArrayList<>();
itemsList.add(new Items(items, isBoolean));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String itemsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(itemsList);
```

POJO

```java
public class Items {

    private List<Item> items;
    private Boolean isBoolean;
```

I get this:

```json
[{"items":[{"itemsCode":"item1","isAvailable":false}],"isActive":false},{"items":[{"entryCode":"item2","isSelected":true}],"isActive":false}]
```

please help how to get rid of an array brackets, but keeping the convention of adding those object to a list in a for loop

Comment: Why do you have a list (`List<List> itemsList= new ArrayList<>();`) if you don't want a list? Or vice versa, why don't you want a list, if you need a list?

Comment: I need two objects created with different values (in a loop) and them make it as a string

Comment: It's a string, if there's no better idea, you can always have a `itemsJson = itemsJson.substring(1, itemsJson.length() - 1);`.

Comment: What you are trying to generate isn't valid JSON, so a JSON library won't be able to generate it. If this really is what you want, consider serializing each `Item` to String separately, then joining those with commas. And then figure out how you're ever going to parse that string back into objects.

Comment: Your String form is JSON and your data model includes a List, so the square braces are correct.  See https://www.json.org/json-en.html.  If your intent is to output some non-JSON form then `ObjectMapper` (I assume this is the Jackson class) may not be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` denote an array, so if your top-level object for serialization is `List` you cannot avoid having them.
If you want to have top-level item as plain objects you need to rewrite the code adding one more POJO:

```java
public class ItemsContainer {
    private List<Items> itemsList;
}

public class Items {
    private List<Item> items;
    private Boolean isBoolean;
}

List<Items> itemsList= new ArrayList<>();
itemsList.add(new Items(items, isBoolean));

ItemContainer container = new ItemContainer();
container.setItemsList(itemsList);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String itemsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(container);
```

Comment: it would be good idea but it adds ItemContainer to the front-->
`{"container":[{"items":[{"itemsCode":"item1","isAvailable":false}],"isActive":false},{"items":[{"entryCode":"item2","isSelected":true}],"isActive":false}]}`

Comment: Otherwise you cannot avoid `[]` as you are serializing a `Collection`